# Is there a 'log2' builtin function or constant value in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix

Remix gives me a warning that I haven't received before:

[image]

Is there a new `log2` builtin function or constant value in Solidity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a log2(), but I don't think it's what you think it might be :-)

The name clash is with the logn (n=0,1,2,3,4) functions used for low-level event logging.

The compiler line declaring it is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/libsolidity/analysis/GlobalContext.cpp#L57).  You'll get the "shadows" warning if you use any of the variables or functions listed in this section.

As for whether it's new, the function is not new, but the warning is. See [this commit](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/commit/e0dc74b895727525f261a9abe190872a58e8999e).